# Can I use SQL Server transaction without using a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, distributed-system

I have two servers that may both try to perform some action. I want to have some form of distributed lock so that only one will perform this action at a time.

I understand that I could use something like ZooKeeper, however that is a lot of infrastructure to setup for one small thing.

I was thinking I could create a table in SQL Server that I access in a transaction. This would work, but seems a but hacky/messy (what if someone later finds the table with nothing in it and decides to delete it etc.)

I was wondering if there was a way of creating 'named' transactions (my made up term) in T-SQL/SQL Server?

FWIW I am using Entity Framework for data access, but I could always use raw ADO.net if needed.

Comment: the sql transaction is bound to the ADO object..  ADO has methods to commit or rollback transactions

Comment: @maSTAShuFu How does Server As ADO object know about the transaction on the ADO object on Server B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a built in thing

```
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(20);  
SELECT @TranName = 'MyTransaction';  

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName;  
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
DELETE FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.JobCandidate  
WHERE JobCandidateID = 13;  

COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-naming-a-transaction

And in C# land, using ADO.Net

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    // Start named  transaction.
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction");

    try
    {      
        //Do work you want locked globally
    }
    finally{
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) to acquire a session level lock on a your own named resource. The lock will be held until explicitly released or the session ends.

```
DECLARE @return_code int;
EXEC @return_code = sp_getapplock
     @Resource = 'YourResource'
    ,@LockMode = 'Exclusive'
    ,@LockOwner = 'Session'
    ,@LockTimeout = 0;
RAISERROR('sp_getapplock return code is %d', 0, 0, @return_code) WITH NOWAIT;
```